# How to add google maps listener on click for an array of InfoWindows inside an array of Markers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, cordova

It's telling me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined"

This is my code

```
var markers = new Array();

            for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i = i + 4){
                if(res[i] == "") break;
                shopLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(res[i + 2], res[i+3]);                  

                markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: shopLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: res[i],
                });

                var infoWindows = new Array();
                infoWindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: res[i + 1]
                });


                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(){
                    infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);                       
                });



                //console.log("Loja: " + res[i]);
                //console.log("Categoria: " + res[i + 1]);                                  
                //console.log("Latitude: " + res[i + 2]);
                //console.log("Longitude: " + res[i + 3]);              
            }
```

The var "res" is an array of strings...

Comment: declare the infoWindows-Array outside of the loop, otherwise it will be overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, using your help and help of @bits my code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing that your variable `i` is not getting `closure`'d for the async click event.

Try changing this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
    infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);
});
```

to this:

```
(function (i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function () {
        infoWindows[i].open(map, markers[i]);
    });
})(i);
```